# Get string before first "$"

Tags: java

I want to get the String before the first `$`. I used the code below but it doesn't give me the required output, which is `name`

```
String sInputFld = "name$name22";

String sOutputFld = sInputFld .split("$")[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is because your delimiter is `$` that has special meaning in regular expression that used in `split()`. You have to escape it:

```
String sOutputFld = sInputFld .split("\\$")[0];
```

EDIT:
However using `split()` for extracting only first fragment seems not effective. You can use `substring()` and `index()`:

```
int dollarPos = str.indexOf("$"); // here $ is not escaped because regex is not used\
if (dollarPos >= 0) {
    fragment = str.substring(0, dollarPos);
}
```

Comment: this is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) and [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) for a String. Something of the sort will do:

```
String s = input.substring(0, input.indexOf('$'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
String string = "name$name22";
String[] parts = string.split("\\$");
String part1 = parts[0]; // name
String part2 = parts[1]; // name22
```

Answer (score 0):

Cange your second line to

```
String sOutputFld = sInputFld .split("\\$")[0];
```

the `$` is a special character in regexp. It means the end of string. so you have to escape it.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I'm able to fetch the variable before first occurence of '$'. How do i get the variable after '$' ?

Comment: @user3684156 Try sInputFld .split("\\$")[1];

Comment: works, how do i check if a String actually contains '$' ? Only then i need to use the split else split[1] fails.

Comment: Try sInputFld .indexOf("$")>-1